# order not giving correct answer after map_dbl

Tags: r, tidyverse

Wondering if the following is a bug...

Data frame

```
df <- data.frame(Name=rep(letters[1:3],each=3), Value=c(20,40,35,70,80,90,10,20,30))
```

Some operations

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- split(df, df$Name) %>%
    map(., ~.x %>% arrange(desc(Value)))
df2 <- map_dbl(df1, ~head(.x$Value, 1))
```

**--LOOK AT DATA**

`head(df2)`

```
 a  b  c 
40 90 30
```

`str(df2)`

```
Named num [1:3] 40 90 30
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

**--BUG?**

```
order(df2)
[1] 3 1 2
```

gives incorrect answer, but

```
df2['a'] > df2['c']
TRUE
```

gives correct answer. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @is my answer clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` in R will return the sorted position in the original list ***order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order***

for example :

```
Dat=data.frame(a=c(2,1,4,6,3),b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
order(Dat$a)
[1] 2 1 5 3 4
Dat[order(Dat$a),]
  a b
2 1 2
1 2 1
5 3 5
3 4 3
4 6 4
```

you are looking for rank *Returns the sample ranks of the values in a vector*

```
rank(Dat$a)
[1] 2 1 4 5 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...I *was* looking for `rank`

Comment: @ChiPak glad it help ~ nice day

Answer (score 0):

By default, `order` has `decreasing = FALSE`. Meaning that it gives *ascending* order. To get order from highest downwards we can do

```
order(df2, decreasing = TRUE)
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: This works, but why is the order when `decreasing=FALSE` equal to `3 1 2`? Shouldn't it give `2 3 1`?

Comment: And 'a' == 'a'.....What should be the answer to `order(df2, decreasing = FALSE)`?